# Modeling Contact in Abaqus

Tags: contacts, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I have simulated a 2D model in Abaqus which indicates 2 main part, first a sector that represent as wheel and, second a rectangular that represent rail.
the wheel and rail are in contact and wheel should rotate and move from left to right. there is a vertical small crack in middle of the rail to studying the result of contact on fracture mechanics.
my model has been completed, and in the 1/10 of total time good result has been achieved but after that the stress distribution is completely wrong and although the contact seems to exist, the stress is almost zero.
Any guide, comment or advice would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: What stress distribution?  Around the crack tip?  How would the stress field change as the wheel moved past if the crack wasn't there?  That will give you a hint.  I would expect the stress to be reduced after the wheel passed.

Comment: http://www.wseas.us/e-library/conferences/2007portoroz/papers/555-162.pdf

Comment: this question is really too broad to be suitable for stack overflow. This site is for specific code issues.  Try the yahoo abaqus group or maybe engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @duffymo this article you send is the basic of hertz contact and my model should follow these rules in entire time but only 1/10 of total time follow. and I can't find what is the mistake of my model. Thank you

Comment: @agentp thank you, I will ask there, too.

Comment: Check your loading.  Perhaps the load history you input is not correct past the 1/10th of the time that you claim.